# jQuery event binding on dynamically created DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry about the ambiguous title but I couldn't think of anything better.

I've been struggling with this issue for a few days and haven't been able to find a way around it. A little background about my code: I have a textbox `savedInfo` and it stores values from different sessions. So if `savedInfo` is empty, I'd like to confront the user with another `textbox`. Once the user inputs info into the `textbox` and presses `enter` then the `.val()` of the `textbox` goes to `savedInfo` and the `textbox` is replaced with a label that has 2 buttons that appear when hovered. These two buttons give the user the ability to remove or save the `textbox`.

The problem I am having is that my code doesn't seem to flow correctly. For instance, I have an if statement that checks if `savedInfo` is empty and if it isn't then show the label text of `savedInfo`. Then INSIDE the `keypress` function I check if one of the hover buttons is pressed but the code doesn't work since it is inside the `keypress` function. If I take it out of the `keypress` function then it doesn't work for when the `keypress` label appears.

Probably best if I explain with pseudo code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($("savedInfo").val() != "") {
  someDiv..innerHTML(<label>$("savedInfo").val() + hover shows buttons</label>);
} else {
   //Create textbox id `textbox`
}

$(function() {
    $("#textbox").keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //set innerHTML to a label with text of `textbox`. 
        //Check if button#1 is pressed. If yes, then do something

        //Check if button#2 is pressed. If yes, then do something
        }
    });
 });
});
```

So the button#1 and button#2 `ids` are being created inside the if but don't work inside the if because they are inside the keypress.

I hope this wasn't too confusing. Any ideas on how to make this work better? Thanks

Comment: So basically you want to generate `keypress` event of dynamically generated button... correct?

Comment: @MokshShah Yeah I suppose that would be a better way of putting it.

Comment: If elements are being dynamically created, you cannot bind to them since they haven't been created and attached to the DOM yet.  What you want to do then is use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on parent element that does exist and provide a selector.  For example, `$(PARENT_ELEMENT).on(EVENT, CREATED_ELEMENT_SELECTOR, CALLBACK)`

Comment: if somthing is dynamically generated, $(function() { or $(document).ready(function() { wont work.... you can use $(document).on("keyup", "#your_id", function(){ // code here });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example with jQuery based off of your requirements.

I really don't understand what the use case is here though and it begs a few questions about reuse of the original text-box, whether this is going to occur multiple times on a page or not, why you wouldn't just show the buttons right away (vs assuming the user knows that they must press enter), and whether this could be better solved using templates?  Seems that this is more difficult than it should be for such a simple interaction.

Anyhow, I hope this helps move you forward.

```js
(function () {

    function promptForInfo(elem) {
        
        var html = "<div id='newInfoContainer'><label>New info: <input id='newInfo' type='text' placeholder='Please provide info...' /></label></div>";
        $(elem).parent().append(html);  
        
        $("#newInfo")
            .focus()
            .on("keydown", function (e) {
                
                if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                    
                    $(elem).val(this.value);
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                    
                    var buttonsHtml = "<div id='buttonContainer'><input class='saveButton' type='button' value='Save' /><input class='removeButton' type='button' value='Remove' /></div>";
                    $(elem).parent().append(buttonsHtml);
                    $(".saveButton").on("click", function (e) { saveInfo(e); });
                    $(".removeButton").on("click", function (e) { removeInfo(e); });
                    
                }            
        });
    }

    function saveInfo(e) {
        $(e.target.parentElement).remove();
        $("body").append("<p>Saved</p>");
    }
    
    function removeInfo(e) {
        $(e.target.parentElement).remove();
        $("#savedInfo").val("");
        $("body").append("<p>Removed</p>");
    }
    
    function inspectSavedInfo() {
        if (!$("#savedInfo").val()) {
            promptForInfo($("#savedInfo"));
        }
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        
        // Inspect on any change after init
        $("#savedInfo").on("change", function () { inspectSavedInfo(); });
        
        // Trigger Inspection of savedInfo on init 
        inspectSavedInfo(); 
    });

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="savedInfoContainer">
    <label>Saved Info: <input id="savedInfo" type="text" value="" /></label>
</div>
```